# Is it possible to see Sonar's Quality Gates change history?

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to see what changes were make into a specific Quality Gate.

I know the Quality Profiles have a changelog indicating which change were made,

Does the Quality Gates have a changelog of historic changes?

Currently working with Sonar Community 8.9.1

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is not a SonarQube feature so far.

The best approach currently is to do a query straight to the database:

```
sonarqube=# select * FROM quality_gate_conditions WHERE qgate_uuid ='AW34stC4j7_z4Lf6i_AM';
 operator | value_error |       created_at        |       updated_at        |         uuid         | metric_uuid |      qgate_uuid      
----------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+-------------+----------------------
 GT       | 10          | 2019-12-03 15:46:18.684 |                         | AXpEV83rANff9M9OJaep | 52          | AW34stC4j7_z4Lf6i_AM
 GT       | 3           | 2019-10-23 09:58:51.494 |                         | AXpEV83rANff9M9OJaeo | 76          | AW34stC4j7_z4Lf6i_AM
 GT       | 0           | 2019-12-03 15:46:32.385 |                         | AXpEV83rANff9M9OJaeq | 51          | AW34stC4j7_z4Lf6i_AM
 GT       | 1           | 2019-12-10 11:18:59.811 |                         | AXpEV83rANff9M9OJaet | 95          | AW34stC4j7_z4Lf6i_AM
 GT       | 1           | 2019-10-23 09:58:51.466 |                         | AXpEV83rANff9M9OJaei | 96          | AW34stC4j7_z4Lf6i_AM
 LT       | 80          | 2019-10-23 09:59:20.001 | 2023-03-17 11:36:36.187 | AXpEV83rANff9M9OJaem | 33          | AW34stC4j7_z4Lf6i_AM
 LT       | 60          | 2019-10-23 09:58:51.493 | 2023-03-20 08:31:44.446 | AXpEV83rANff9M9OJaeu | 34          | AW34stC4j7_z4Lf6i_AM
```

Notes:

- Only last update date is shown (not who did it or what was the previous value)
- **AW34stC4j7_z4Lf6i_AM** is the Quality Gate id